# Array of blittable struct not pinned when marshaling?

Tags: c#

From [Blittable and Non-Blittable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types)

> The following complex types are also blittable types:
>
> - One-dimensional arrays of blittable types, such as an array of integers. However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable.
> - Formatted value types that contain only blittable types (and classes if they are marshaled as formatted types). For more information about formatted value types, see Default Marshaling for Value Types.

and

> As an optimization, arrays of blittable types and classes that contain only blittable members are pinned instead of copied during marshaling.

So according to the above documentation, an array of blittable struct will be pinned when marshaling. But when I tried in a simple program, I got two different addresses of the array in the managed and c++ side.

```
// c#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyPoint
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var array = new MyPoint[1];
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Console.WriteLine("0x" + handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToString("X"));
        LibWrap.TestPinningOfArrayOfStructs(array);
    }
}

public class LibWrap
{
    [DllImport("..\\LIB\\PinvokeLib.dll")]
    public static extern void TestPinningOfArrayOfStructs(MyPoint[] pointArray);
}

// c++
typedef struct _MYPOINT
{
    int x;
    int y;
} MYPOINT;

PINVOKELIB_API void WINAPI TestPinningOfArrayOfStructs( MYPOINT* p )
{
    printf("0x%p\n", p);
}
```

The output is

```
0x26322FC
0x005CC3A8
```

Am I misunderstanding something?